# Split dataframe column after apply method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have this code to clean LinkedIn job titles:

```
def clean_title(position):
    if 'back-end' in position.lower():
        return 'Backend Developer'
    elif 'front-end' in position.lower():
        return 'Frontend Developer'
    elif 'full-stack' in position.lower():
        return 'Fullstack Developer'
    elif  '-' in position.lower():
        return position.split('-')[0].strip()
    elif  '|' in position:
        return position.split('|')[0].strip()
    elif  '(' in position:
        return position.split('(')[0].strip()
    elif ':' in  position:
        return position.split(':')[1].split('-')[0].strip()
    elif '-' in  position:
        if '-' in position.split('-')[0].strip():
            return position.split('-')[0].split('-')[0].strip()
        else:
            return position.split('-')[0].strip()
    else:
        return position

df['Position'].apply(clean_title).value_counts()
```

After execute previous code, I still have some job titles incorrect.
After applying clean_title function, I want to split the titles that still have the hifen (-) char.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYKbJ.png

How can I proceed?

Comment: Can you show us the original, unprocessed table?

Comment: More useful information:
https://i.imgur.com/THhb8Hm.png
https://i.imgur.com/7d6h8WO.png
https://i.imgur.com/ZCoDCYA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to recursively call `clean_title()`.  Maybe an implementation like:

```
def clean_title(position):
    if 'back-end' in position.lower():
        return 'Backend Developer'

    if 'front-end' in position.lower():
        return 'Frontend Developer'

    if 'full-stack' in position.lower():
        return 'Fullstack Developer'

    if  '-' in position:
        return clean_title(position.split('-')[0].strip())

    if  '|' in position:
        return clean_title(position.split('|')[0].strip())

    if  '(' in position:
        return clean_title(position.split('(')[0].strip())

    if ':' in  position:
        return clean_title(position.split(':')[0].strip())

    return position
```

Comment: Much thanks, it worked using it recursively :)

Comment: @DiogoFernandes, if helps and works for you then you should upvote & accept it as an answer.